# How to reduce height of ios app in (designed for iPad) mode in Apple silicon M1

Tags: ios, swift, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to run my iOS application on M1 (designed for iPad), App is running fine but my bottom Tabbar is hiding behind the Doc at the bottom.

My app supports only 1 orientation i.e. Portrait (bottom home button).

[image: This is the actual result I am getting]
[image: This is how I want to show bottom tabbar but above doc, or reduce the size of app view]

Comment: Mac users expect their apps to be resizable, for the most part. You should accommodate that.

Comment: @Alexander you are right, but currently, I just want this situation to be satisfied.
because of some UI-related limitations, I can't allow resizing.
if you know any way to bring tab bar above the Doc or reduction of height then please let me know.
it would be a great help.

Comment: Well the only real correct answer to that is "resolve those 'UI-related limitations', and allow resizing." 